# ul li background color change vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Please help. I need list of N numbers from an array with background color e.g yellow and pink changed on click for each li element.
Like  1 background: yellow,
      2 background: pink,
      3 background: yellow
      4 background: pink etc.

I am having now same background-color for all li elements on every click event, the color is changing but it's changing all of them same time.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        isDark: false,
        log: [],
        count: 1
    },
    methods:{
    somefunc: function(){
        this.log.push(this.count++);
        this.isDark = !this.isDark;
    }
}
});



  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <div >
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(ing, i ) in log" :class="[ isDark ? 'background-yellow' : 'background-pink' ]"  >
         {{ ing }} 
      </li>
      </ul>
      <button @click="somefunc">Press</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It makes sense that the color changes for all of the items, because they're all referencing the same instance of `isDark` which is defined on the Vue instance. Instead, you'll need to either set an `isDark` property on each element in the `log` array, or have a separate array with each index and its `isDark` value. With a separate array:

```js
data: {
    logColors: [],
    ...
},
methods: {
    somefunc () {
        this.log.push(this.count++)
        this.logColors.push(!this.isDark)
    }
}
```

In the template markup for the `li` element:

```html
<li ... :class="logColors[i].isDark ? 'background-yellow' : 'background-pink'">
...
</li>
```

If you want to have `isDark` as a property of the items in `log`:

**Script**

```js
methods: {
    somefunc () {
        this.log.push({ value: this.count++, isDark: !this.isDark })
    }
}
```

**Markup**

```html
<li ... :class="log[i].isDark ? 'background-yellow' : 'background-pink'">
{{ing.value}}
</li>
```